# How do you map collections conditionally with Hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-annotations

If I have a class structure which looks like the following (annotations removed):

```
public class Person {
  String store;

  Swatch swatch;

  Collection<Paint> paints;
}

public class Swatch {
  String color;
}

public class Paint {
  String color;

  String store;
}
```

Store is never null and is the key used between Person and Paint.  The goal is to match all Paint records with the same color as the Swatch with the same store as the Person.  However, the Swatch may be null or its color attribute may be null (in both cases return all Paints with the same store as the Person).

Is there a JPA or Hibernate based annotation that will construct this query on the paints collection?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for a query that you should construct.

Answer (score 0):

I concluded that this is either impossible with Hibernate annotations or perhaps just not very obvious.

My solution was rather hackish: on Person I have a Transient annotated method which filters paints programmatically.  Less than ideal because it may force an additional query to grab the Swatch entity.

I will not mark this as correct as I think Vineet Reynolds' answer to create a query is probably most reasonable in the case I presented.  However, a query is harder to implement in my real scenario due to unmentioned factors which I thought were irrelevant to my example and mentioning them would have added significant complexity.